# Datagrid detailed view of selected rows visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am having a `Datagrid` with some set of values.
I need to display it in another grid when a row of the Data grid is selected.I have binded that grid with datagrid. Its all working fine.

I need to display that detailed view only when any row in the datagrid is selected. Otherwise it should be hidden.

How can i acheive it?
Since am a beginner i couldn't figure out how to acheive this.
I ll be glad if i get some responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change visibility of grid object with datatrigger e.g. where Datagrid has name LISTNAME

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=LISTNAME, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="-1">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
```